# Powershell - An empty pipe element is not allowed problem

Tags: powershell

I Tried running this in powershell

> cd "c:thetesttun2" ; if ($?) { nvcc thetestrun2.cu -o thetestrun2 } ; if ($?) { .\thetestrun2 } | Out-File "C:\thetesttun2\hellow.txt"

and this error keeps coming up

`An empty pipe element is not allowed. + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement`

Please help I am new to powershell

Please give me some code to run on my machine

Comment: `if ($?) { .\thetestrun2 } | Out-File "C:\thetesttun2\hellow.txt"` is not valid PowerShell, perhaps you meant `if ($?) { .\thetestrun2 | Out-File "C:\thetesttun2\hellow.txt" }`?

Comment: Use `$( )` If you want to pipe from a statement or multiple pipelines:  `$(  if ($?) { nvcc thetestrun2.cu -o thetestrun2 } ; if ($?) { .\thetestrun2 }  ) | Out-File C:\thetesttun2\hellow.txt`  or enclose in `& { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in comments, a pipeline statement cannot begin with a control flow structure like `if(...){...}` - the first element has to start with either a *value expression* or a *command element*.

There's a couple of options for solving this. If you simply want the output from the eventual invocation of the program, move `| Out-File` into the `if` body:

```
cd "c:thetesttun2"
if ($?) { nvcc thetestrun2.cu -o thetestrun2 }
if ($?) { .\thetestrun2 | Out-File "C:\thetesttun2\hellow.txt" }
```

If you also want to stream the output from the compilation to the file, wrap the whole thing in a scriptblock `{...}` (thus turning the whole thing into a command element) and invoke with the `&` call operator:

```
cd "c:thetesttun2"
& {
  if ($?) { nvcc thetestrun2.cu -o thetestrun2 }
  if ($?) { .\thetestrun2 }
} | Out-File "C:\thetesttun2\hellow.txt"
```

Finally, you can also wrap the `if` statements in the `$(...)` subexpression operator or the `@(...)` array subexpression operator, thus turning the whole thing into a *value expression*:

```
cd "c:thetesttun2"
@(
  if ($?) { nvcc thetestrun2.cu -o thetestrun2 }
  if ($?) { .\thetestrun2 }
) | Out-File "C:\thetesttun2\hellow.txt"
```

... but beware that this will *block* while executing the statements, and output won't start streaming until the subexpression has been fully evaluated, thus incurring higher memory allocations for the process - which is why I suggest the scriptblock approach detailed above instead :)

Comment: Thank you Mathias R Jessen This Solution worked and I am continuing my work by using &{} Thank you very much once again